# CSS Grid column width

Tags: css, css-grid

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--per-row), minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 2px;
}

.grid-item {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
  background: #008aa6;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 6%), 0 6px 8px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 8%);
  color: white;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 24px 8px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 484px) {
  --per-row: 2;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 485px) and (max-width: 961px) {
  --per-row: 3;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 962px) {
  --per-row: 6;
}
```

```html
<ul class="grid-container">
  <li class="grid-item"><span>1</span></li>
  <li class="grid-item"><span>2</span></li>
  <li class="grid-item"><span>3</span></li>
  <li class="grid-item"><span>4</span></li>
  <li class="grid-item"><span>5</span></li>
  <li class="grid-item"><span>6</span></li>
</ul>
```

I have a grid container that can hold 2, 3 or 6 col in one row (variable $per-row depends on the breakpoint) `grid-template-columns: repeat($per-row, minmax(0,1fr));`  with the `grid-gap: 2px;`.
For some reason I can't get exactly the same width elements. For example, when computed on large  breakpoint with 6 col this gives me: `246.328px 246.336px 246.336px 246.328px 246.336px 246.336px`. Why do I get this difference of 0.08px? This makes my unit tests fail.

Comment: Can you provide a live example?

Comment: Where are you testing this? Is there a reason you are using `min/max-device-width` instead of `max/min-width`? This seems more like a browser rounding error since Firefox is calculating all elements at the same width.

Comment: @disinfor actually I am using max/min-width. Min/max-device-width is just a copy/paste mistake. And you are right, this width calculation issue only occurs in Chrome, in Firefox is fine. Thanks!

Comment: This is a rounding error in chrome, there are a couple other SO questions/answers that address this.